# Make 'edit' button trigger edit-mode on UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

This might be a very stupid question, but I have very little knowledge about Xcode, Objective-C and iOS development in general.

What I have is a UITableViewController, with a number of cells. I've gotten the 'add' and delete (swipe to delete) functions to work, but I cannot figure out how to connect the 'edit' button to a function that will trigger the editing mode of that TableView, so I can rearrange the order of the elements.

I have un-commented these functions:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    XYZToDoItem *itemToMove = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.toDoItems removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [self.toDoItems insertObject:itemToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

As you can see I have also made a few additions to the moveRowAtIndexPath method following the documentation.

In addition there are these functions;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.toDoItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

As previously stated the "swipe to delete" function works, I don't know how, but I simply just uncommented these last two methods and edited one a bit to fit my code.

To be more specific, what I'm asking is how can I link the 'edit' button I have in my Navigation Controller to trigger the edit mode for the TableView, thereby showing the three lines (?) known from the TableViews editing mode (and letting me drag the elements to an order I want).

Thanks in advance for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a UITableViewController you have two options. Either use the built-in edit button, which will give you the automatic Edit/Done button change. Use `self.editButtonItem` in your navigation bar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Or you could use `setEditing:animated` to change editing state of the tableViewController:

```
// self is a UITableViewController
[self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

If your viewController is not a subclass of UITableViewController you can set the editing mode of the tableView:

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

---

If you have a UITableViewController you should use the first way because it is most convenient.

Comment: Thanks a million, the first solution worked! :)

The only thing is now that if I go to the storyboard, there won't be an 'edit' button showing there. What I tried to do last time was to use a 'bar button item' then 'identifier: edit'. 

If I wanted to go that way, how would I solve it so that edit button toggles edit mode?